# How to send an Email from Gmail Delegate Account using Python?

Tags: python, delegates, gmail

I wanted to send the mail on Gmail from delegate account using python. As I logged in using my primary email ID and password, so the python script send the mail from my primary account instead of Delegate account.

How to send mail from Gmail delegate account using python?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

> I wanted to send the mail on Gmail from delegate account using python.

[Delegation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/delegate_settings) is preformed using service account authentication.  For it to work it must be configured by the admin of your google workspace account

- [Perform Google Workspace Domain-Wide Delegation of Authority](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation)

> As I logged in using my primary email ID and password

Delegation can not be performed using a login and password. Nor can it be configured using a standard gmail account. It only works for google workspace domain accounts.

## python delegation to service account

Note: create_delegated is the email address of the user on the workspace domain you would like the service account to delegate as.

```
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_p12_keyfile(
        SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL,
        SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH,
        'notasecret',
        scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send'])

    credentials = credentials.create_delegated(user_email)
```